# How to show visit time for the second time to open `welcome.php`?

Tags: php, timestamp

There are two php file :`welcome.php` and `check.php`.
The `welcome.php`  is as below.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_COOKIE["user"]["xm"] <> "")
{
    $visnum = intval($_COOKIE["user"]["num"])+1;
    setcookie("user[num]" , $visnum , time()+3600);
    setcookie("user[dt]" , date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ,time()+3600);
    echo "welcome  " . $_COOKIE["user"]["xm"];
    echo  "<br />This is your " . $visnum . "  th" . "  visit my website";
    echo  "<br />The latest visit time is  " .$_COOKIE["user"]["dt"] ;

}
else
{
    echo
        '<html><body><form method="post"  action="check.php">
           user: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="xm" size="12"><br />                        
           password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="Pwd" size="12"><br />
          <input type="submit" value="login"><br />
        </form></body></html>';
}
?>
```

The `check.php` is as below.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["xm"] == "admin" && $_POST["Pwd"] == "123")
{
    setcookie("user[xm]" , $_POST["xm"] , time()+3600);
    setcookie("user[dt]" , date("Y-m-d h:i:s") , time()+3600);
    echo  $_POST["xm"] . "  :Your first visit  ";
}
else
{
    echo  "<script>alert('user name or password is wrong');location.href = 'welcome.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

The check.php will show `admin :Your first visit`  when to input `admin` in user and `123` in `password` in welcome.php.

```
  admin :Your first visit
```

This is your first time to click `127.0.0.1/welcome.php`

Then to click `127.0.0.1/welcome.php` in browser for the second time,the output is as below:

```
welcome admin
This is your 2 th visit my website
The latest visit time is
```

Notice:time stamp is not in the above output.
To click `127.0.0.1/welcome.php` in browser for the third time,the output is as below:

```
welcome admin
This is your 3 th visit my website
The latest visit time is 2018-08-11 12:09:36
```

How to show visit time  for the second time to open `127.0.0.1/welcome.php` in my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method1:use cookie.
Rewrite  `welcome.php` as below.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_COOKIE["user"]["xm"] <> "")
{
    $visnum = intval($_COOKIE["user"]["num"])+1;
    setcookie("user[num]" , $visnum , time()+3600);
    echo "welcome  " . $_COOKIE["user"]["xm"];
    echo  "<br />This is your " . $visnum . "  th" . "  visit my website";
    echo  "<br />The latest visit time is  " .$_COOKIE["user"]["dt"] ;
    setcookie("user[dt]" , date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ,time()+3600);
}
else
{
    echo
        '<html><body><form method="post"  action="check.php">
           user: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="xm" size="12"><br />                        
           password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="Pwd" size="12"><br />
          <input type="submit" value="login"><br />
        </form></body></html>';
}
?>
```

Method2: use  session.
Thanks for `K Sudbury's` reminder.
Rewrite  `welcome.php` as below.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_COOKIE["user"]["xm"] <> "")
{
    $visnum = intval($_COOKIE["user"]["num"])+1;
    $expire = intval($_COOKIE["user"]["expire"]);
    setcookie("user[num]" , $visnum , time()+3600*$expire);
    echo "welcome  " . $_COOKIE["user"]["xm"];
    echo  "<br />This is your " . $visnum . "  th" . "  visit my website";
    echo  "<br />The latest visit time is  " .$_SESSION["visit"] ;
    $_SESSION["visit"] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
}
else
{
    echo
        '<html><body><form method="post"  action="check.php">
           user: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="xm" size="12"><br />                        
           password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="Pwd" size="12"><br />
          <input type="submit" value="login"><br />
        </form></body></html>';
}
?>
```

Rewrite `check.php` as below.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["xm"] == "admin" && $_POST["Pwd"] == "123")
{
    setcookie("user[xm]" , $_POST["xm"] , time()+3600);
    setcookie("user[expire]" ,1 , time()+3600);
    setcookie("user[dt]" , date("Y-m-d h:i:s") , time()+3600*$expire);
    $_SESSION["visit"] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    echo  $_POST["xm"] . "  :Your first visit  ";
}
else
{
    echo  "<script>alert('user name or password is wrong');location.href = 'welcome.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["visit"])) {
    $_SESSION["visit"] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
}else{
    echo "Your first visit was {$_SESSION["visit"]}";
}
```

Try using [Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will check if it has a value, if not then it will set the time. However, if it is set then it will show the time.